# Problem with creating channel in category

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a channel in the category of the users choice but the program is running until the third line only. It doesn't even give me an error. I saw similar questions but they were either giving me an error or the category was already pre-defined in them.

Here's my code:

```py
if sly.content.startswith("sly tcatchancreate"):
    tcatchan = sly.content.split("sly tcatchancreate ",1)[1]
    await sly.channel.send("enter the category to make the channel in. Msg should be in 'sly categ (name)' format")
if sly.content.startswith("sly categ"):
      tcateg = sly.content.split("sly categ ",1)[1]
      await sly.guild.create_text_channel(tcatchan,overwrites=None, category=tcateg, reason=None)
```

Comment: i changed the way the program works by using the .split  to divide the input in three parts but it shows me an error saying maximum 2 args are there but mine has 3. pls check

if sly.content.startswith("sly tcatchancreate"):
    tcatchan=sly.content.split("sly tcatchancreate ",1,2)[1]
    tcateg=sly.content("sly tcatchancreate ",1,2)[2]
    await sly.guild.create_text_channel(tcatchan,overwrites=None, category=tcateg, 
    reason=None)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to wait for user input right? Please look at the documentation for `wait_for`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for